# Forwarded Tomcat through Apache uses wrong Context path

Tags: apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Okay let me explain my problem really fast. I have a JEE Programm running on my tomcat server. The server has some user defined in the tomcat-users.xml When i test my programm on my local machine everything works fine.

However if i deploy the .war on my server and i want to access a Rest Endpoint i get a 401 unauthorized error. If i remove the users security check i can work fine with the program. So the URLs and server setup is correct.

I think that the problem is somehow related to the forwarding of tomcat through my apache.

So lets assume i have an apache running on http://myIp.de

then i forwarded tomcat with following apache config:

```
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass /tomcat http://localhost:8181/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse /tomcat http://localhost:8181/
```

so now i can reach tomcat through: http://myIp.de/tomcat
also i can "speak" to my app via: tomcat/myApp

But somehow the Authentizication now fails. And i think the problem is 
somehow related to wrong context path. Because tomcat/manager
also fails to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life easier by deploying your app under `/tomcat` on tomcat too. This way there's no path-translation required. Keep in mind that you'll get all the session cookies tied to a specific path and this path is not necessarily translated once forwarded to the client.

Also, sooner or later you might need

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

(look it up) or utilize `mod_jk` to preserve this header (and more information) automatically.

Edit: Following your comment, Basic Auth headers seem not to be forwarded to tomcat as well. I haven't attempted this myself, but all the places that I've looked up seem to imply that there'd be some duplication (e.g. second credentials file for Apache) - that doesn't look good. In this case I'd suggest to try out mod_jk rather than mod_proxy. You'll use the `JkMount` directive, rather than `ProxyPass` and need a workers.properties, but mod_jk is a lot better in keeping the full context of the request when forwarding to tomcat. I've had good experience with it so far and have only heard little complaints about it - largely in situations that were pretty huge and complex/complicated anyway. At least you should try if it solves your problems.

Comment: Okay, this looks like an easy solution to my problem. But im not completly sure what you suggest me to do. Im currently deploying "myApp" in /opt/tomcat/webapps/myApp . And i access it via myIp/tomcat/myApp/. Now you suggest me to put myApp in /opt/tomcat/webapps/tomcat/myApp or /opt/tomcat/myApp ? Im not sure how this would help me ? Thanks.

Comment: In the question you name the context /tomcat, in the comment /myapp. Whatever you name it, make sure that it's the same name on apache as well as on timber. E.g., assuming no firewalls and both installed on the same server, http://hostname/myapp and http://hostname:8080/myapp should be the same asp

Comment: Okay, now i got it. So the links are fine now, but i still get a 401 unauthorized error when try to access the rest endpoints. Im pretty sure that the configs in the web.xml and in the tomcat-users.xml are fine, because it works when i test it locally without the apache forward. Also when i disable the security constraint in the web.xml its also works fine. Its like the HttpBasicAuthFilter somehow gets lost on the way to tomcat. And then tomcat refuses the request. Do you have any idea why this is ? Thanks a lot Olaf !